# Codeigniter unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this page error that

```
This page isn’t working 35.173.0.77 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

but it works fine in localhost and some other page as well.
I've tried to put `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` both controller and model but that didn't work.

it works fine even in live server before but when I added some features, the error keep on showing. I checked my new line of codes and I don't think there's wrong in my new line of codes since its working in localhost.

[image]

Comment: enable error reporting to see error.

Comment: Try enable debug mode - https://pakainfo.com/codeigniter-enable-disable-debug-mode/

Comment: Your web server (Apache, nginx, etc) logs, and/or PHP logs, will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a "server-side" error, meaning the problem is a problem with the web site's server. 
Please check your apache error logs, you can find some interesting information in there.
Just in case:

1. Check your PHP version is it compatible with your Codeigniter version
2. Check Your .htaccess module

Comment: This answer saved me a lot troubles. The Apache's error.log told me where to go. Cheers!